# PhantomJS script is run from meteor method but does not create an image when I call render

Tags: node.js, meteor, phantomjs

I take a list of urls from a input, e.g "http://google.com;http:facebook.com" and then send it to a meteor method. From there I want to run a PhantomJS script that is in the /private directory and save a screenshot of those urls in the current folder.
All the console.logs run and says that everything's fine but there is never any images saved in the directory!

Meteor Server Method:

```
    Meteor.methods({
  screenshots: function(urls) {
    // Wait for async code to run
    Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
    var fut = new Future();

    // Check urls argument
    check(urls, String);
    var urlArray = urls.split(";");

    // The local top level directory
    var path = require('path');
    var base = _.initial(path.resolve('.').split('/')).join('/');
    var phantomjs = Meteor.npmRequire('phantomjs-prebuilt');
    var childProcess = Meteor.npmRequire('child_process');
    var spawn = childProcess.spawn
        var binPath = phantomjs.path;

    childArgs = [
      // the path to the bundled version of '/private'...
      base + '/server/assets/app/create_screenshots.js'
        ];

    for(var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) {
        childArgs.push(urlArray[i]);
    }

        childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('arguments', arguments);
      fut.return(arguments);
        });

    return fut.wait();;
  }
});
```

PhantomJS script with binary exe in same folder

```
"use strict";
var arrayOfUrls;
var system = require("system");

if(system.args.length > 1) {
    //arrayOfUrls = Array.prototype.slice.call(system.args, 1);
    arrayOfUrls = Array.prototype.slice.call(system.args, 1);
} else {
  console.log('Url addresses is required');
  phantom.exit();
}

// params: array with urls, a callback that renders the current url, callback that ends script
var RenderUrlsToFile = function(urls, callbackPerUrl, callbackFinal) {
    var getFilename, next, page, retrieve, urlIndex, webpage;
    urlIndex = 0;
    webpage = require("webpage");
    page = null;

    getFilename = function(url) {
        return url
            .replace(/^(http|https):\/\//, '')
            .replace(/\/$/, '') + ".png";
    };

    next = function(status, url, file) {
        page.close();
        callbackPerUrl(status, url, file);
        return retrieve();
    };

    retrieve = function() {
        var url;
        if(urls.length > 0) {
            url = urls.shift();
            urlIndex++;
            page = webpage.create();
            page.viewportSize = {
                width: 800,
                height: 600
            };
            page.settings.userAgent = "Screenshot Bot";
            return page.open(url, function(status) {
                var file;
                file = getFilename(url);
                if(status === "success") {
                    return window.setTimeout((function() {
                        page.render(file);
                        return next(status, url, file);
                    }), 200);
                } else {
                    return next(status, url, file);
                }
            });
        } else {
            return callbackFinal();
        }
    };
    return retrieve();
};

RenderUrlsToFile(arrayOfUrls, (function(status, url, file) {
  if(status !== "success") {
    return console.log("Unable to render '" + url + "'");
  } else {
    return console.log("Rendered '" + url + "' at '" + file + "'");
  }
}), function() {
  return phantom.exit();
});
```

The script returns Console.log("Rendered '" + url + "' at '" + file + "'") but no image has been saved to the current directory.

Thank you for your time!